# In a sentence extract specific word including whitespace in R

Tags: r

I need to get the specific word including white-space  in R.

For example I have a restaurant list like this:

```
r_list <- c('mexicana', 'macdonald', 'KFC')
```

and I have a list of sentences which explains about those restaurant, like:

```
sentense <- c('I really like mexi cana', 'want to eat mac donaldso much!', 'I hateKF C')
```

Ultimatly I want to use for-loop to grep nrow of each restaurant.

```
grep('mexicana', sentense)
```

When I grep mexicana, I can't grep it.

So I thougt of trie algorithm but 'triebeard' package don't works when I use it with korean.

I hope you guys help me. What should I can do???

Is there only 'gsub' function in the way???

Comment: There's a risk of doing so, but you can preprocess with `gsub("\\s", "", sentense)`, using that return value to `grep("mexicana", gsub("\\s", "", sentense))`.

Comment: But when I use for-loop then I think I don't know the way using gsub in grep....(sob sob)

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample data? Please specify the rules.

Comment: when I run grep("mexicana", sentense, value=T) or use else function, then I want to get "I really like mexi cana"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

My idea was to remove all spaces from `sentense`, upper case `sentense` and `r_list` (so it will be easier to match), match using `grep`.

Sample data:

```
r_list <- c('mexicana', 'macdonald', 'KFC')

sentense <- c('I really like mexi cana', 'want to eat mac donaldso much!', 'I hateKF C')
```

Solution:

```
require(tidyverse)

sentense %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(concatenate = toupper(gsub("[[:space:]]", "", value)), 
         eating = grep(
           pattern = paste(
             toupper(r_list),
             collapse = "|"), 
           x = concatenate), 
         eating = r_list[eating])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  value                          concatenate               eating   
  <chr>                          <chr>                     <chr>    
1 I really like mexi cana        IREALLYLIKEMEXICANA       mexicana 
2 want to eat mac donaldso much! WANTTOEATMACDONALDSOMUCH! macdonald
3 I hateKF C                     IHATEKFC                  KFC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want extraction via regular expressions, you can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`.

```r
( nospaces <- gsub("\\s", "", sentense) )
# [1] "Ireallylikemexicana"       "wanttoeatmacdonaldsomuch!" "IhateKFC"                 

re <- gregexpr(paste(r_list, collapse = "|"), nospaces)
regmatches(nospaces, re)
# [[1]]
# [1] "mexicana"
# [[2]]
# [1] "macdonald"
# [[3]]
# [1] "KFC"
```

So the return value from `gregexpr` is a list with attributes:

```r
str(re)
# List of 3
#  $ : int 12
#   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 8
#   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
#   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
#  $ : int 10
#   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 9
#   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
#   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
#  $ : int 6
#   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int 3
#   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
#   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
```

In the list, the first `[[1]]` element is for the first string `"Ireallylikemexicana"`, etc. Within that list, the 12 means that there was a match starting at the 12th character, and it was 8 characters long. Repeat for the others.

This will match and extract multiple matches in a single string.

```r
others <- c("quuxmexicanaoKFCmmmsdkfj", "quux")
str(re <- gregexpr(paste(r_list, collapse = "|"), others))
# List of 2
#  $ : int [1:2] 5 14
#   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int [1:2] 8 3
#   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
#   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
#  $ : int -1
#   ..- attr(*, "match.length")= int -1
#   ..- attr(*, "index.type")= chr "chars"
#   ..- attr(*, "useBytes")= logi TRUE
str(regmatches(others, re))
# List of 2
#  $ : chr [1:2] "mexicana" "KFC"
#  $ : chr(0)
```

In this case, the second list element (for `"quux"`) is -1, meaning no match found. This results in an empty (`character(0)`) placeholder in the list's second position. In this case, you can get all of the matches *regardless of which string* by using `unlist`.